# How to scroll inner scroll bar in selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, scrollbar

I have been trying to scroll inner scroll bar on a page (There is no Iframe) but every time driver was focusing on outer scroll bar. How can I control the inner scroll bar? Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this worked for me:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('elementsId').scrollBy(0,100)");
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer and for contributing to Stack Overflow. If you could provide some explanation of what your answer  does, that would further improve its quality.